# Disable multiple week days in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable multiple week days in JavaScript for a calendar that i am using. Currently i have tried the following code and it works perfectly fine and Sunday gets disabled. How can i disable multiple week days using JavaScript getDay() Method in JavaScript?

```
disabled: function (date) {
  if (date.getDay() === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Requesting help.

Comment: if (date.getDay() === 0 || day.getDay() ==6) doesn't or condition work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple days might take an array and check if the day is in the array:

```
 disabled: function (date) {
   return [0, 6].includes(date.getDay());
 }
```

Or might use some tricky bitshifting (just kidding :)):

```
 disabled: function (date) {
   return 1 & ( 0b1000001 >> date.getDay());
 }
```

---

off-topic: To also disable all dates prior today, just do a small comparison:

```
  disabled: function (date) {
   return (
      [0, 6].includes(date.getDay()) ||
      date < new Date
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use or condition

```
 if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6)
```

Comment: Thank you. You have a typo in your code. day.getDay() instead of date.getDay().